# Instructions for installing `youtube-dl` from source code - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: git, make, youtube-dl, configure

I have recently had some [issues installing `youtube-dl`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296054/youtube-dl-appears-to-be-in-an-awful-mess-what-is-the-true-install-procedure-f) on Ubuntu 20.04. **THIS IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION**. Those issues [have been resolved](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296056/1152544), but I am not:

- a Python user
- [comfortable with `snap` yet](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23052108)

And it seems the `apt` repository is not maintaining a current, operational version of `youtube-dl`, so my *preferred* approach won't work.

It seems that installing `youtube-dl` from source would be a good solution. I've not done this on Ubuntu, and have very limited experience on any plaform. I've found [what appears to be a decent guide](https://www.ubuntupit.com/install-software-from-source-code-in-your-linux-system/), but nothing specific for `youtube-dl` on Ubuntu. Is there anything else I should know before proceeding?

---

#### Other Notes (Edit):

Just to confirm that `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` has issues:

> Preparing to unpack .../12-youtube-dl_2020.03.24-1_all.deb ...
> Unpacking youtube-dl (2020.03.24-1) ...
> Setting up youtube-dl (2020.03.24-1) ...

After the `apt` installation of `youtube-dl` completes *successfully*:

```
$ which youtube-dl
/usr/bin/youtube-dl 
$ youtube-dl --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory
$ /usr/bin/youtube-dl --version
2020.03.24
```

Which *suggests* to a newbie such as I that something is amiss. Note that there is confusion wrt where `youtube-dl` is installed: `/usr/bin` vs `/usr/local/bin`. And it clearly installs an old (March, 2020) version.

Using the install procedure from the [`youtube-dl` github page](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/tree/2020.11.26) yields this:

```
$ sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl  
$ sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl  
$ youtube-dl --version
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

For reasons unclear to me, the `youtube-dl` maintainers want the installation in `/usr/local/bin`. No idea why `python` is expected in `/usr/bin/env`.

All the above is to address various comments made since this Q was submitted.

And yes, if I uninstall/remove/reverse the `apt` install, and delete the `curl`'d d/l to `/usr/local/bin`, I can successfully install and run `youtube-dl` using `sudo pip3`. But some caution that `sudo pip3` should NOT be done - rather it should be *virtualenv* (or something like that) instead. That is why I have posted this question: **I don't want to use something I don't don't use & don't understand because I can't maintain it.** I don't think that's unreasonable or makes me recalcitrant. I just want to know how to install `youtube-dl` from source - if that is a reasonable thing to do given all of the above.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS & release, but I have no issues with my `apt` installed `2020.11.21.1` version (you're likely to have a different version if your release differs). Why not just `pip3` install it as Gunnar Hjalmarsson suggested.  It's worked for me in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [youtube-dl appears to be in an awful mess - what is the true install procedure for 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296054/youtube-dl-appears-to-be-in-an-awful-mess-what-is-the-true-install-procedure-f)

Comment: The Ubuntu repositories **are** maintained, but as it's a 'universe' package, it's maintained by the Community, and it's not recorded that a package needs to be refreshed until a user who is having an issue, then files a bug reporting a re-package is required. Users reporting issues starts the process of maintenance.   As I stated before, I've done that a couple of times with `youtube-dl` and the upgraded package usually is available 28-52 hours later (as it's community packaged, it's a volunteer in their own time packaging it, and delays can occur, but the process is started with bug filing)

Comment: @guiverc: My OS & release are Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - I thought that was clear from the question, but if I overlooked something, pls advise. And pls also note, I also asked the question you referenced  - did you miss the links in this question?

Comment: Sorry, details in headings are not always visible once the question is open depending on the device & browser being used to read the site. Thus all relevant details in headings should also exist in the question; where no release is mentioned on your page.

Comment: @guiverc: As I indicated in this [referenced question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296054/youtube-dl-appears-to-be-in-an-awful-mess-what-is-the-true-install-procedure-f), I installed `youtube-dl` from the `apt` repo, and got a version from March of this year. And being installed from `apt`, it must be upgraded via apt.

Comment: I don't program in python either, but using `pip3 install youtub-dl` I don't consider difficult, which you mentioned but also highlighted an issue... I'll see if I can find a recent 20.04.2 QA-test install & have a play for you.

Comment: A clean (other than the few commands I use to verify the QA-test install) 20.04.2 install was booted, `sudo apt install python3-pip`, followed by `pip3 install youtube-dl`, next `sudo ln -s /home/guiverc/.local/bin/youtube-dl /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` so it can be found (it's quick) then a `youtube --version` reports the version as `2020.11.26`  which is **not** the version you got in your prior question.  It works too downloading a youtube video.

Comment: I can write up what I did as an answer, it's what I'd do, in fact just did on a *fresh* (*except for some `df` & like commands checking out the Quality Assurance install of the un-released Lubuntu 20.04.2 system; in reality it's just a 20.04 system. and I can't see Lubuntu making any difference; it was used as available*), but I don't see that as anything beyond what has already been covered in your prior question.`--upgrade` doesn't make sense on a first install in your question so I didn't use it; my use of `ln` could be done other ways; but I find that way quick so used it..

Comment: @guiverc: I have added an extensive edit in an effort to address all of your comments and questions. If I indicated that the `pip3` install did not get the `2020.11.26` ver of `youtube-dl` then I have mis-communicated. I think I said it worked in this question, and I accepted the answer I got on the previous question. Yes... it works, but as explained in my Edit, I don't want to use that solution. I think between Ubuntu & yt-dl, something is broken. It **seems** that installing from source **may be** a solution, but I don't know - thus, the question.

Comment: `pip3 install youtub-dl` will install the source (a python3 script).  You can then use `whereis` to locate where it was placed (I may have used `whereis` before I use the `ln` in prior comment), then a `file` can be used to confirm it's python3. eg. a `file ..../youtube-dl` reports "`Python script, ASCII text executable`"  (ie. that is the source code; python3 is both source code & executable).  I dropped (....) the path as this is the `apt` installer version on this box (2020.11.21.1) so I wouldn't expect it to be the same path as pip3 installed version I tested on *focal* 20.04.2 box

Comment: I just see my `youtube-dl` is now an old version.... 2020.11.29 has come out... new versions of `youtube-dl` come out very regularly ... the *focal* version I tested (prior comment) worked though on the music video *I download & subsequently listened to.

Comment: FYI:  Whilst some languages are compiled into executable code (eg. C), most scripting languages (like python) are just interpreted by interpreters, and thus the source code and executable are one & the same thing.

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` when you install with `pip` (and you really shouldn't because it's not necessary). You simply need to add the `--user` flag to your `pip` command to install locally. After you install locally with pip for the first time, you will need to log out and log back in but this will not be necessary in the future. I have provided a simple answer below.

Comment: @guiverc You don't need to `ln` that local directory to /usr/local/bin so it can be found. You just need to log out and log back in after the first time you install something to `$HOME/.local/bin` as this directory is conditionally added to your path (if it exists) by `~/.profile`.

Comment: If you used the `ln` command, just run the following command `rm $HOME/.local/bin/youtube-dl` and then follow my instructions below.

Comment: @mchid I realize that; but the `ln` command was far quicker than logout/login (esp. given it took me ~4 goes to remember which password was used in that QA-test)...

Comment: Also, the reason they want it installed in `/usr/local/bin` is so that the downloaded version will override the version from `apt`. Also, if the `apt` version is updated, it won't overwrite your downloaded version. Typically, applications installed from source or manually downloaded will install in `/usr/local/bin` to allow `apt` version to stay installed which you may need for dependency reasons (so that other packages don't break due to dependencies) although, that shouldn't be an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Before you begin, run the following commands to fix your `#!/usr/bin/env python` "No such file or directory" error:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Now, your problem is most likely solved. However, you can check out the following instructions if you want to install from source.

---

Make sure all the old versions are uninstalled:

```
sudo apt purge youtube-dl
sudo pip3 uninstall youtube-dl
pip3 uninstall youtube-dl
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
rm $HOME/.local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now, install from source:

```
cd
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
sudo apt build-dep youtube-dl
git clone https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git
cd youtube-dl
make
sudo make install
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If you used the `ln` command earlier, just run the following command `rm $HOME/.local/bin/youtube-dl` and you may need to run `pip uninstall youtube-dl` then follow my instructions in this answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Seamus In any case, I added the instructions for installing from source.

Comment: @Seamus Although, it the same as the pre-compiled downloaded version anyhow (if you run `make` and `sudo make install` without changing any options).

Comment: If that's the case, I wonder why doing the [**manual installation**](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#installation) results in an error when you try to run it? Specifically: `bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory` after installing it in `/usr/local/bin`?? Why is this? `usr/local/bin` is in my PATH, `which` knows it's in `usr/local/bin`. Not trying to be an a$$hole, but what I see on my system doesn't agree with what you say. If I've made another error, please let me know.

Comment: I didn't see your extensive edits until after I posted my previous comment. It's a much better answer now AFAIC, but I question the statement that ... `install python-is-python3` is going to fix the `No such file or directory error`. It will address the `/usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory` error. On my system I used `hash -r` to resolve this ([see my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296788/831935)). After struggling with the same issues as the OP, I **think** this is the way to go.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I was referring to the `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory` since it appeared the `/usr/local/bin` error was resolved when they installed the downloaded version. Anyhow, fixed it by adding a command at the end to source the `~/.bashrc` file just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason you are getting the error is due strictly to the fact that your shell saves the location of executables (and other things) to its **cache**. In other words:

After you installed `youtube-dl` using `apt`, you then entered a command to check the version (`youtube-dl --version`). At that point, `/usr/bin/youtube-dl` was stored in the **cache**. This is *efficient* because it avoids searching your PATH each time you enter that command. But if you then re-install `youtube-dl` using the manual installation procedure, the new location is `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`. But the **cache** is not updated by the new "installation", nor is it updated when you run `apt remove` on the `youtube-dl` package you installed. Consequently, the shell tries to run the wrong executable - or even one that's no longer there.

#### Proposed Answer:

The solution to the `No such file or directory` error is this:

```bsh
$ type youtube-dl 

# this will likely show the following: 
youtube-dl is hashed (/usr/bin/youtube-dl) 

# if this is the case, your "fix" is one of the following:

$ hash -r

# which will delete the entire cache
# --OR--

$ hash -d youtube-dl  

# which will delete only the entry for youtube-dl
```

`hash` is a `bash` *built-in*; search for `hash` in `man bash` for more details. For `zsh` users, the analog to `hash` is `rehash`.

Also, the `youtube-dl` **manual** installation was done in `/usr/local/bin` iaw long-standing procedure [explained in this article on Linux directory structure](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained/). This is as it should be - no fault to Ubuntu or to the yt-dl maintainers.

#### Installing From **source**:

This answer does not address your question re "installing from source". Another answer proposes an approach for this, but I doubt that installing from source would have avoided the `No such file or directory` error in any case - except possibly by accident - for example you started a new session.